# Flush lowest-ranking card

Tags: flush

Im just confused how to interpret lowest-ranking card when there is a flush.
On the board: Ah Kh 8h Jh 9d Player 1 7h 3h Player 2 6h 4h. Who wins?

Comment: This is a dupe, the winner has the best 5 card hand, so in this case player 1, their flush is AKJ87h, whereas player 2 has AKJ86h

Comment: So basically saying "by the rank of its lowest-ranking card" in this contest is same as to say"by the rank of its fifth highest- ranking card", correct?

Comment: I think it would be easier to rank flushes by the rank of the highest card, since no two flushes can have the same high card in a given hand.

Comment: Ok thanx. Cuz thats what i took from wikipedia and it confused me.

Comment: @Clarko Uh, this hand did

Comment: With community-card games, matching cards are common. The rule is the same: poker hand have exactly FIVE CARDS, no more, no fewer.

Comment: @Paparazzi woops, i like to go from highest to lowest when comparing 5-card hands, it is less confusing.

Comment: @Clarko It is a shared board.  Two flushes can have the same high card.